# NodeJs Buffer CRLF

Tags: node.js, bluetooth, buffer, newline

I want to use Nodejs [bluetooth-serial-port](https://www.npmjs.org/package/bluetooth-serial-port) plugin and Buffer to send "be\r\n" to my Bluetooth device. (It's works only with that)

With [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.sash0k.bluetooth_terminal) Android tool it's working.

The problem is my Bluetooth device can't recognise the message.
Here is my code:

```
var btSerial = new (require('bluetooth-serial-port')).BluetoothSerialPort();

btSerial.connect(device, channel, function () {
    var data = new Buffer('be\r\n', 'utf-8');
    console.log('connected, sending: ' + JSON.stringify(data.toString('utf-8', 0, 4)));

    btSerial.write(data, function (err, bytesWritten) {
        if (bytesWritten) {
            console.log("writed: " + bytesWritten);
            btSerial.close();
            console.log("disconnected.");
        }
        if (err) console.log(err);
    });

    btSerial.on('data', function (buffer) {
        console.log(buffer.toString('utf-8'));
    });

}, function () {
    console.log('cannot connect');
});
```

And the output:

```
connected, sending: "be\r\n"
writed: 4
disconnected.
```

Comment: What is your question/problem?

Comment: You are disconnecting immediately after you write, so it probably doesn't have any time to get data?

Comment: @jfriend00 It doesn't working, I using a PIC for reading BT RX data in my BT device. And the microcontroller can't parse the message, because it can ONLY understand "be\r\n".

Comment: @loganfsmyth I close the connection in the write function's success call back.

Comment: Then, describe what debugging steps you've already taken.  Are you receiving the connection on the device?  Are you receiving any data on the device?  If so, what data are you receiving on the device?  Does any action need to be taken on the device in order to accept the bluetooth connection or to pair the two devices?

Comment: I tried using ascii encoding, and  Buffer.concat "be" and "\r\n". Unfortunately I can't view what's the PIC receiving. I using Debian Linux with ARM arch, and I always get this message in the dmesg when I run the program: Bluetooth: Wrong link type (-71) But, with my Android device it's working. In the PIC's program, the command defines as: 

unsigned char parBe[4] = "be\r\n";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution: The Bluetooth agent **must run** to work with bluetooth-serial-port, and also the encoding have to be ASCII.